# GpuMat to FFMPEG Encoder

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I'm doing some image processing with opencv::cuda so what I end up with is a cv::cuda::GpuMat. I now want to encode it using ffmpeg(so I can choose the encoder to be hardware accelerated or not). Now I wonder if i can somehow keep the data on the GPU for the encoder without downloading it, because that seems to be the bottleneck in my application running multiple threads.

I'm resizing the images with Opencv CUDA so I have less to download. (resizing with sws_scale makes no difference)

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat currentFrame;
...
cv::cuda::GpuMat resized;
cv::cuda::resize(currentFrame,resized,cv::Size(width*0.75,height*0.75),0,0,cv::INTER_NEAREST);
cv::Mat frameEnc = cv::Mat(resized);
const int stride[] = { static_cast<int>(frameEnc.step[0]) };
sws_scale(swsctx, &frameEnc.data, stride, 0, frameEnc.rows, avframe->data, avframe->linesize);
ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec, avframe);
if(!ret) {
    /* rescale packet timestamp */
    pkt->duration = 1;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec->time_base, vstrm->time_base);
    /* write packet */
    av_write_frame(outctx, pkt);
}
```

Now this does work and performs ok, but I really wish I could do something like:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat currentFrame;
...
GpuMatToAvFrame(currentFrame,avframe);
ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec, avframe);
if(!ret) {
    /* rescale packet timestamp */
    pkt->duration = 1;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec->time_base, vstrm->time_base);
    /* write packet */
    av_write_frame(outctx, pkt);
}
```

where the avframe data is also on the gpu so that I don't download need any transfer between GPU-CPU/CPU-GPU

Answer (score 1):

I think the class [cv::cudacodec::VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dde/classcv_1_1cudacodec_1_1VideoWriter.html) could help, once an issue with OpenCV gets fixed. The class allows you to write a GpuMat directly. However I believe that due to [a bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14850) in OpenCV, you can't build OpenCV with support for this class. Which means this isn't a great solution now, but might be in the future.